# How to change the size (width and height) of progressbar to fit all in linearlayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, loops, android-layout

I would like to add an unknown amount of progressbar to a linearlayout.
(Like Whatsapp Status, and Instagram Stories)
I can add progressbar to the linearlayout but the progressbar just shows max 7 progressbar.[image: progressbar with 7 progressbar even though should be 10]

My code so far:

```
while (i < 10){
    i ++;
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stories_progress, null);
    linearLayout.addView(child);
}
```

I would like to shrink the size of the progressbar programmatically,
so when I have 2 progressbar, they fill the layout with 50%/50%,
when 5, 10 or even 20 progressbar, they become smaller, all of them will be displayed on linearlayout
I tried to get the current width of the linearlayout and divide by
the number of progressbars, but the width of the linearlayout returns always 0;

My xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".stories">

</LinearLayout>
```

My progressbar

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/stories_progressBar_id"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ProgressBar>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that you are not waiting for the top *LinearLayout* to have a size. You can wait for a size to be assigned by using a [ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener). Here is some code that should help:

```
linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        int newWidth = linearLayout.getWidth() / 10;
        int newHeight = linearLayout.getHeight();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            i++;
            LinearLayout child =
                    (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.stories_progress,
                            linearLayout, false);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = newWidth;
            lp.height = newHeight;
            linearLayout.addView(child);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. It works like water charm. You are the best.

Comment: I have another question. I would like to get the at a specific index the element (progressbar) of the linearlayout elements: I tried using a loop throught the linearlayout elements and getChildAt(index) and tried to set a value to the progressbar but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Make sure that you are setting the progress bar value correctly and are actually finding the progress bars and not something else. If you are still stumped, you may want to consider asking another question. There is nothing in this question that tells me what you are doing and it would not be appropriate to update this question to asked a different question.

Comment: I posted another question explaining my problem and what I tried so far. I would very much appreciate if you would take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73402369/how-to-get-programmatically-the-children-of-same-type-from-linearlayout