# How to get programmatically the children of same type from linearlayout?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-linearlayout

I have a linearlayout with many progressbars (horizontal progressbars).
I can add programmatically many progressbar to my linearlayout as I want.
But I would like to get a progressbar in a specific index.
for example: If I add 4 progressBar to my linearlayout.
And I want to get the second progressBar and set a progress and max progress just to the second progressbar in my linearlayout.
I tried to loop through all the children of linearlayout and get the child in a specific index what it doesn't work.

```
// add progressbar to linearlayout
        linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                linearLayout.removeAllViews();

                int newWidth = linearLayout.getWidth() / 7;
                int newHeight = linearLayout.getHeight();
                while (i < 7) {
                    i++;
                    LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().
                            inflate(R.layout.stories_progress,
                                    linearLayout,
                                    false);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                    lp.width = newWidth;
                    lp.height = newHeight;
                    linearLayout.addView(child);
                }
            }
        });

        // get progressbar children of linearlayout at a specific index
        int count = linearLayout.getChildCount();
        View v = null;
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            // i want the progressbar in index 1 (the second)
            v = linearLayout.getChildAt(1);

            // this code produces a blank page in my app
            ProgressBar pg = (ProgressBar) v;
            pg.setProgress(20);
            pg.setMax(100);
        }
```

I'm triyng to achieve the same result as Instagram Stories, where when an user posted 4 images/videos, we see above the 4 progressbars and seeing the first video/image (at index 0) the progress settings is activated to start counting.

My stories progress:

```
    <LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">
    
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/stories_progressBar_id"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ProgressBar>
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

My Activity layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".stories">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add `R.layout.stories_progress` with question .. Also why do u need `GlobalLayoutListener`?

Comment: You should post the layout you are inflating. The child you are retrieving may not be the progress bar. Try `v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i).getChildAt(1)` to see if that works. Also, if you app is crashing, you should look at the error message and post the relevant logcat messages if you need to.

Comment: I edited the question and added the layout I'm inflating and my main layout. I tried v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i).getChildAt(1) and it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't get any error. It just doesn't show anything.

Comment: You are trying to change the progress of views that haven't been added yet. You need to put the progress change code within the global layout listener after the views are added and make the change I suggested in the other comment.